# Using powershell to add new AD user doesnt add samaccountname with AD LDS

Tags: active-directory, powershell-3.0, active-directory-group, adam

I'm guessing there is some limitation with LDS as I can't add samaccountname when running the following command:

new-aduser -samaccountname "bobman" -name "bobtest" -server "localhost" -path "OU=Users,DC=test,DC=local"

A new user account is created on LDS but the samaccountname property remains blank.

Running the above command on a full instance of AD creates the user and samaccountname successfully which makes me think this is a limitation with LDS or thers another way to add it.

Is there a way around this as I'd like to populate samaccountname on LDS?

The above command isn't the full command in my script as that reads from a CSV file and creates a list of users so I produced a basic command to only populate a few fields to test it out.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found some pages online which confirmed new-aduser does not have the ability to add a value for samAccountName as it is not in the LDS schema.

[Link one](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/9b9a13dc-6575-4b55-8cdc-727dc5cc681a/stand-alone-ad-lds-missing-samaccountname-in-user-class?forum=winserverDS)

[Link two](http://blog.joeware.net/2011/03/04/2214/)

To get around this issue I have wrote a script which generates a LDF file with content as follows for each user:

dn: CN=Bob Test,OU=Users,DC=Server,DC=local

changetype: modify

replace: samAccountName

samAccountName: bobman

-

I then used LDIFDE to run the above LDF file which populated samAccountName successfully.